# Optimize this query getting exceed recourse limit

Tags: sql, database, db2

```
SELECT DISTINCT                                  
    A.IDPRE                                   
    ,A.IDARTB                                  
    ,A.TIREGDAT                            
    ,B.IDDATE                                
    ,B.IDINFO                                
    ,C.TIINTRO                                 
FROM
    GLHAZQ  A                                 
    ,PRTINFO B                                 
    ,PRTCON  C                                 
WHERE
    B.IDARTB   = A.IDARTB                     
AND B.IDPRE    = A.IDPRE                      
AND C.IDPRE    = A.IDPRE                      
AND C.IDARTB   = A.IDARTB                     
AND C.TIINTRO  = (
    SELECT MIN(TIINTRO)          
    FROM
    PRTCON D              
    WHERE D.IDPRE = A.IDPRE  
    AND D.IDARTB  = A.IDARTB)
ORDER BY C.TIINTRO
```

I get below error when I run this query(DB2)

```
SQL0495N  Estimated processor cost of "000000012093" processor seconds   
("000575872000" service units) in cost category "A" exceeds a resource limit error  
threshold of "000007000005" service units.  SQLSTATE=57051
```

Please help me to fix this problem

Comment: If you use aliases as `A`, `B` and `C` you deserve whatever you got ;-)

Comment: I cant use aliases since these fields needs to be uses with same name , i have to follow the coding standard

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the workload manager is doing its job in preventing you from using too many resources. You'll need to tune your query so that its estimated cost is lower than the threshold set by your DBA. You would start by examining the query explain plan as produced by `db2exfmt`. If you want help, publish the plan here, along with the table and index definitions.

To produce the explain plan, perform the following 3 steps:

1. Create explain tables by executing `db2 -tf $INSTANCE_HOME/sqllib/misc/EXPLAIN.DDL`
2. Generate the plan by executing the explain statement: `db2 explain plan for select ...<the rest of your query>`
3. Format the plan: `db2exfmt -d <your db name> -1` (note the second parameter is the digit "1", not the letter "l").

To generate the table DDL statements use the `db2look` utility:

```
db2look -d <your db name> -o tables.sql -e -t GLHAZQ PRTINFO PRTCON
```

Comment: HI, Thanks for your reply. it seems logical since it worked with one development and not with test. can please tell me how to get the plan and table index definiton

Comment: Hi.. We dont have access to work with plan. Can you please suggest some query optimization stuff. Other solution @DRapp suggested works fine but takes 50 secs to return result.

Comment: @Hems You should work with your DBA to understand the resource limits and get assistance to tune the query.

Comment: @Hems - "query optimization stuff" is based on the ability to see its plan. Trying to optimize a query without tools is like trying to diagnose a disease by the patient's photograph.

Answer (score 1):

Although not a db2 person, but I would suspect query syntax is the same.  In your query, you are doing a sub-select based on the C.TIINTRO which can kill performance.  You are also querying for all records.

I would start the query by pre-querying the MIN() value and since you are not even using any other value field from the "C" alias, leave it out.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      A.IDPRE,
      A.IDARTB,
      A.TIREGDAT,
      B.IDDATE,
      B.IDINFO,
      PreQuery.TIINTRO
   FROM
      ( SELECT D.IDPRE, 
               D.IDARTB, 
               MIN(D.TIINTRO) TIINTRO
           from 
              PRTCON D
           group by 
              D.IDPRE, 
              D.IDARTB ) PreQuery
         JOIN GLHAZQ  A
            ON PreQuery.IDPre = A.IDPRE
            AND PreQuery.IDArtB = A.IDArtB
         JOIN PRTINFO B
            ON PreQuery.IDPre = B.IDPRE
            AND PreQuery.IDArtB = B.IDArtB
   ORDER BY 
      PreQuery.TIINTRO
```

I would ensure you have indexes on

```
table      Index keys
PRTCON     (IDPRE, IDARTB, TIINTRO)
GLHAZQ     (IDPRE, IDARTB)
PRTINFO    (IDPRE, IDARTB)
```

If you really DO need your "C" table, you could just add as another JOIN such as

```
JOIN PRTCON C
  ON PreQuery.IDArtB = C.IDArtB
  AND PreQuery.TIIntro = C.TIIntro
```

With such time, you might be better having a "covering index" with

```
GLHAZQ table key ( IDPRE, IDARTB, TIREGDAT )
PRTINFO    (IDPRE, IDARTB, IDDATE, IDINFO)
```

this way, the index has all the elements you are returning in the query vs having to go back to all the actual pages of data.  It can get the values from the index directly

Comment: Hi .. Thanks for your solution. it is working fine. but it takes 50 sec to return result. Please suggest if you have any better solution

Comment: Without knowing the volume of data, at least it ran vs what you had :) with respect to resource limits being exceeded :)  Did you try by adding the PrtCon that I added at the bottom of the answer?  If that has less records might help.  Are there any other criteria, such as any specific item, date, status criteria to limit?  How many records in the database per respective table included in the query.  One more item per adjusted answer though.